# What is the Intel Processor Generation of my CPU?

Tags: cpu

I want to know the generation of the following Intel CPU:

> Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7600 @3.06 GHzRAM 4GB

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "Intel Processor Generation" only applies to Intel CPUs branded as:

1. Core i3
2. Core i5
3. Core i7
4. [Core M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_M_microprocessors) (but not always)
5. [Core i9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i9_microprocessors)
6. Xeon E3
7. Xeon E5
8. Xeon E7
9. Xeon D
10. Xeon Phi
11. Pentium (without suffix; and only if produced in 2010 or later)

Your CPU is from none of these brands and is older than them. It is now called *Legacy Intel® Core™ Processors*.

The phrase "Intel Processor Generation" **does not apply** to the following Intel CPU brands:

1. Intel Core Solo
2. Intel Core Duo
3. Intel Core 2 Solo
4. Intel Core 2 Duo
5. Intel Core 2 Quad
6. Intel Core 2 Extreme
7. Intel Celeron
8. Intel Atom
9. Intel Quark